# Waterfall Case Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, case

I am trying to write a case statement that returns a single value as soon as it finds the right value from a each "WHEN" statement. Once it finds a qualifying value, the query should not try to evaluate the other statements.

```
SELECT
    DT1.COMPANY_ID
    , CASE
    WHEN DT1.RATING_NUMBER = 2 THEN DT1.UNIQUE_ENTRY_ID
    WHEN DT1.RATING_NUMBER = 1 THEN DT1.UNIQUE_ENTRY_ID
    WHEN DT1.RATING_NUMBER = 3 THEN DT1.UNIQUE_ENTRY_ID
     END AS UNIQUE_ENTRY_ID
FROM
    RATINGS_DATA DT1
```

SAMPLE DATA

```
create table COMP_RESULTS (COMPANY_ID varchar2(20),RATING_NUMBER number, UNIQUE_ENTRY_ID varchar2(20));

insert into COMP_RESULTS values ('Org00001','1','ENTRY_C1_1');
insert into COMP_RESULTS values ('Org00001','2','ENTRY_C1_2');
insert into COMP_RESULTS values ('Org00001','3','ENTRY_C1_3');
insert into COMP_RESULTS values ('Org00002','2','ENTRY_C2_2');
insert into COMP_RESULTS values ('Org00002','3','ENTRY_C2_3');
insert into COMP_RESULTS values ('Org00003','3','ENTRY_C3_3');
```

For each day, rating numbers are released for each company; sometimes all of them, sometimes not all). If the rating number is 1, it produces a corresponding unique ID. If the rating number is 2, a correspoding ID is released. If rating '1' is released the query bring the Company ID and the corresponding `UNIQUE_ENTRY_ID` for it. it should not bother looking at the second "WHEN" statement. If Rating Number '1' does not exist, then it tries 2 if neither exists then 3 etc. etc.

SAMPLE RESULTS

```
Org00001    2   ENTRY_C1_1
Org00002    2   ENTRY_C2_2
Org00003    3   ENTRY_C3_3
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected results

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but isn't this how SQL CASE statements work? Are you trying to do something different than normal?

Comment: Note that a CASE WHEN works like that. As soon a WHEN criteria is valid it breaks out of it, ignoring the WHEN's after it.

Comment: Are you getting multiple rows back for each company, but you only want the value from the row that matches first, for each company? Where does 'each day' fit in - what days? Can a company have more than one row for the same rating number, and if so how will you decide which associated entry ID to use? *Please* add sample data and expected results to your question (with an **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54221251/edit)**, not as comments).

Comment: @JoshuaTinashe . . . This is how `case` expressions work, so the question is unnecessary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff not quite because the result set would bring every match and not exclude things where they are not necessary. Try computing it with the sample data and compare against the sample expected results

Comment: @JoshuaTinashe - it *is* how a case expression works. You're asking the wrong question... you're problem isn't how case expressions work, it's that you're trying to use one to solve a problem that it isn't suitable for.

Comment: @JoshuaTinashe You're conflating two different concepts. Your original question asked about conditionally displaying a result value. You seem to also be asking about filtering all of your results based on the conditions you specified. You would use a `WHERE` clause to filter the results, and a `CASE` statement isn't really needed in your `SELECT`. If you have more than one row, you can use window functions to assign a value to the row you need and then filter on that value. I would suggest that you update the question so that it's clearer what you are asking for.

Comment: Are you looking to get the most recent rating that matches your criteria or the first one your query comes to? If you have multiple records and no ordering, you aren't guaranteed to get the same result every time.

Answer (score 3):

A case expression does stop evaluating the terms as soon as it finds a match. So I think you're asking the wrong question. It doesn't look like you really want a case expression at all.

From your sample data and results you seem to want an aggregate using [`first`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/FIRST.html#GUID-85AB9246-0E0A-44A1-A7E6-4E57502E9238), something like:

```
select dt1.company_id,
  max(dt1.unique_entry_id)
    keep (dense_rank first order by dt1.rating_number) as unique_entry_id
from comp_results dt1
group by dt1.company_id;

COMPANY_ID           UNIQUE_ENTRY_ID     
-------------------- --------------------
Org00001             ENTRY_C1_1          
Org00002             ENTRY_C2_2          
Org00003             ENTRY_C3_3
```

This still evaluates every row, but then aggregates and only keeps the one with the lowest `rating_number` - which matches the order of precedence you want.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=efcf0dd7508cdbb9a19a24550ef0db77)

After your edit, if the rating numbers aren't in numeric order, you can add a case expression back into the `order by` clause to specify the desired order:

```
select dt1.company_id,
  max(dt1.unique_entry_id) keep (dense_rank first
    order by case dt1.rating_number
             when 2 then 1
             when 1 then 2
             when 3 then 3
      end) as unique_entry_id
from comp_results dt1
group by dt1.company_id;
```

[Updated db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bf38f477d2064b25b28ce6840721a2f8)

Comment: This would work if the rating IDs are applied in a specific order. Unfortunately that is not the case

Comment: @JoshuaTinashe - how so? In your question you said the ratings are in that order, and this gets the result you asked for.

Comment: I actually understand now - I need to rank the data first based on the criteria! Thank you, you are right, I am asking the wrong question!

Comment: I may still be misunderstanding the question. This won't filter the results for only the `RATING_NUMBER` OP is looking for. Add another record for `RATING_NUMBER` is 42, and it will get picked up in the results of this query.

Comment: @Shawn - if you add 42 for one of those three company IDs then it won't be shown; the case expression evaluates to null, and by default that orders last. If you have a customer with only 42 then it will be shown, yes. It isn't clear if there can be any other values though, and/or if only those three should be filtered (I don't read it as needing filtering, but it isn't specified either way), but that's trivial to add if needed. It also isn't clear if a customer can have more than one row for a rating, or how to handle that if it can - hopefully there's another column to add to the order-by...

Comment: @AlexPoole True. Until Oracle, in their divine wisdom, decides to default sort `null` first. :-) After reading over this question a couple of times and then the follow-up comments, I'm beginning to feel that this may be an XY Problem. There seem to be a lot of details missing that can significantly change the final answer.

Comment: Yes, X made no sense so I answered the Y derived from the data and results... There is a lot missing but this seems to have pointed the OP in the right direction at least.